# Login with django-allauth can't find url for account

Tags: python, django, authentication, oauth-2.0, django-allauth

I'm trying to add Nationbuilder as an oauth provider for my django project, however when I go to accounts/login, and select nationbuilder as the site to login with, I get this issue

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/nationbuilder/login/theHaven.nationbuilder.com/oauth/authorize?scope=profile&state=8zavoKRVmjQr&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Faccounts%2Fnationbuilder%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2F&response_type=code&client_id=3a1993a96815d56593d9850334edf6a9891c537f8255ba39ba0f2f87412db556

This is my [code now](https://gist.github.com/ama4tf/75f243df6b930f9879ff). Nationbuilder is still working on enabling login via oauth, so that could be the issue, however it seems as though it's a problem on my end

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In views.py of nationbuilder, I was missing the https:// in the profile url